# Can someone explain how the following query works in Oracle10g?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle10g, left-join

- The following are the two queries.  I couldn't find how it works.
- Infact the 1st query is not returning any values but the 2nd query
  returns few rows.

```
   select nvl(cdm.dest_id, s.dest_id)
          from my_approval s
          left join my_alias c
          join my_destalias cdm
            on c.cust_id = 73 on cdm.alias_id = c.alias_id
           and cdm.alias_id = s.dest_id
           and s.type = 1;
```

and

```
 select nvl(cdm.dest_id, s.dest_id)
      from my_approval s
      left join my_alias c
        on c.cust_id = 73
      join my_destalias cdm
        on cdm.alias_id = c.alias_id
       and cdm.alias_id = s.dest_id
       and s.type = 1;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you a trying to achieve, describe your data set, tables etc. I think though that the problem lies with your joins usually you (roughly) join an id on a foreign key, so query 2 would return something though probably not what you are wanting. Perhaps look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) not to sure about oracle but I definitely think your joins are wrong.

Comment: Have you looked at the query plans for either of the queries? I'm with @TomIngram that your joins are incomplete or incorrect.

Comment: I checked the query plan and nothing wrong with the join. It executes well. Since I used this query in a pl/sql block and the table is a global temporary table I don't have table data.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, those two queries look like they are trying to accomplish the same thing.  The first one should not execute, because you cannot have two ON clauses for a JOIN.  The second query looks just like the first, except the offending ON clause has been moved to the proper place.

As for how it works, this query will select rows FROM the "my_approval" table.  It will display the dest_id from the "my_destalias" table.  However if that value is NULL, it will display the dest_id from "my_approval" instead.

Rows will only be returned if there is a matching row in the "my_destalias" table (based-on alias_id matching with dest_id and alias_id from "my_alias"), as the plain "JOIN" keyword specifies a join of equality (aka INNER JOIN).  It should be noted, that rows in this query will only be returned if my_destalias.alias_id is equal to BOTH my_approval.dest_id AND my_alias.alias_id.

The LEFT (outer) JOIN specified to the "my_alias" table should still return data if there is not a match present (cust_id = 73).  Of course, your inner JOIN is dependent on a match being returned from this table (cdm.alias_id = c.alias_id).  I'm thinking that the "c.cust_id = 73" should be a part of your WHERE clause instead, and one of the next JOIN's conditions should be used in your LEFT JOIN, instead.

Essentially, your ON clauses are short-circuiting your query and limiting your results.  Without knowing (exactly) what you're trying to accomplish (or what your tables look like), give something like this a try:

```
SELECT NVL(cdm.dest_id, s.dest_id)
FROM my_approval s
INNER JOIN my_alias c ON c.alias_id = s.dest_id
INNER JOIN  my_destalias cdm ON cdm.alias_id = s.dest_id
WHERE s.type = 1
AND c.cust_id = 73;
```

This takes all of your literal values out of your ON clauses, and into your WHERE clause.  Based on your post, you are trying to return rows where cdm.alias_id is equal to both c.alias_id and s.dest_id.  I have put those conditions in your ON clauses.  Based-on how inter-dependent these three tables are, I opted to go with two INNER JOINs (no LEFT JOIN).

Comment: You are right but check the on,on join condition 1st join is on my_alias table and the second join is on my_destalias table. And the inner join not producing the expected result I want.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for my question...

1st Query

```
 select nvl(cdm.dest_id, s.dest_id)
          from my_approval s
          left join my_alias c
          join my_destalias cdm
            on c.cust_id = 73 on cdm.alias_id = c.alias_id
           and cdm.alias_id = s.dest_id
           and s.type = 1;
```

It works like the left join the join condition  `c.cust_id = 73` works like a left join but only if it finds the matched record then it will return the rows.

2nd Query

```
select nvl(cdm.dest_id, s.dest_id)
      from my_approval s
      left join my_alias c
        on c.cust_id = 73
      join my_destalias cdm
        on cdm.alias_id = c.alias_id
       and cdm.alias_id = s.dest_id
       and s.type = 1;
```

This is pretty simple I guess. It works based on the join condition 
(i.e) 1st `left join` with `my_alias` and `join` with `my_destalias`.
Thx for all those who responded for this question.